# Alternative to Little-Snitch app-firewall or LuLu for Ubuntu in 2019

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, firewall

There is an almost identical question made back in 2012.

Many things since them have changed in the Linux world and opensource software.

I would like to get a software recommendation to solve the following:

I would like to know which programs are trying to access the internet and be able to make rules like allowing some software to access and other programs to be isolated. All this if possible in GUI or graphic interface.

Thanks

Comment: I've just found FirePromt but I don't have any information about the developers or the software.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using UFW? It's simple and configurable.

```
sudo apt install ufw gufw
```

Launch *GUI UFW* with your favorite launcher there you can see what apps are using internet and on which port specifically.

[image]

After all you can ban the app from accessing the *internet* on a specific *port* or block the entire *service* in *Rules* section.

[image]